# Vector size is not correct - how can we initialize a vector inside a structure

Tags: c++, c++11

I have below sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef struct defs
{
    std::vector<int> myvec;
} dvec;

typedef struct devdef: public dvec
{
    dvec dvec1;
    devdef()
    {
          dvec1.myvec.push_back(10);
    }
}myVec;

class A
{
public:
    A():v1()
    {
         std::cout << "my vec size is " << v1.myvec.size() << std::endl;
    }
private:
    myVec v1;
};

int main()
{
     A a1;
}
```

Compile and execute:

```
$ c++ -std=c++11 try58.cpp

$ ./a.exe
my vec size is 0
```

I was expecting the size of vector to be 1 - why the same is 0?

Comment: What's up with those `typedef`'s everywhere? You don't need them

Comment: They are user defined struct - just a coding style

Comment: Such confusion, much wow

Comment: @Programmer That's a style used in c because `struct` doesn't define a type name there. In c++ you don't need to `typedef` them since `struct` create type names.

Comment: `dvec1.myvec.push_back(10);` pushes data to a different vector, than you are trying to reference in `v1.myvec.size()`.

Comment: I"m upvoting @Zereges because this looks like a bad transition from C to C++. Deriving a new struct from the old, and adding in another member of the same type as that already present in the base.... plus the typedef thing. I think that OP would benefit from some "compare/contrast" tutorials for C programmers moving to C++

Comment: Thanks after I read v1.dvec1.myvec.size() I was able to get the correct size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version, I think, does what you wanted.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct dvec
{
    std::vector<int> myvec;
}

struct myVec : public dvec
{
    myVec()
    {
          myvec.push_back(10);
    }
}

class A
{
public:
    A():v1()
    {
         std::cout << "my vec size is " << v1.myvec.size() << std::endl;
    }
private:
    myVec v1;
};

int main()
{
     A a1;
}
```

Some notes about what I've changed.

1. There's no need to use a `typedef` to create a new type. In C++ both `class` and `struct` define new types.
2. When deriving the new type `myVec` from `dvec`, it contains the vectror `myvec`, so there is no need to add a new one.
3. In the constructor for the derived type `myVec`, we can access the `myvec` member of the base type directly, since it is a member of this object.

Answer (score 2):

You have `dvecs` as both a parent to `myVec` as well as a member of `myVec`. In your constructor you push a value to `dvec1.myvec`, but in `A` you read `v1.myvec` aka the member of the parent. You simply have two instances of `dvecs` in your structure and you're using different ones in your functions.

Comment: Thanks after I read v1.dvec1.myvec.size()  I was able to get the correct size